# como pasarle un valor de mi base de datos a un input de mi vista editar con laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, html5, bootstrap

hola amigos tengo un problema con un input tipo datetimepicker(ese input me sirve para seleccionar fecha y hora) la cuestion es que mando los datos a la vista y en el value pongo `value="{{$promociones->fecha_fin}}"`y no me muestra el dato en el input de mi vista y parece en blanco...lo raro que al darle inspeccionar elemento desde mi navegador me aparece con los datos correctos en el value pero en input no se ve ese dato

este es la libreria que estoy usando para el datetimepicker [datetimepicker](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Usage/)

este es el script para usar el datetimepicker...en el formato le he puesto Y-MM-D H:mm para que se guarde sin problemas en mi base datos mysql(no use carbon porqur me da demasiados errores al momento de parsear la fecha de formato Dia/mes/año a Año-mes-dia)

```js
$(function () {
        $('#startdate').datetimepicker({
            useCurrent: false,
            format: 'Y-MM-DD H:mm',
            minDate: moment()
        });
        $('#enddate').datetimepicker({
            useCurrent: false,
            format: 'Y-MM-DD H:mm',
            minDate: moment()
        });
        $("#startdate").on("change.datetimepicker", function (e) {
            $('#enddate').datetimepicker('minDate', e.date);
        });
        $("#enddate").on("change.datetimepicker", function (e) {
            $('#startdate').datetimepicker('maxDate', e.date);
        });
    });
```

mi input desde inspeccionar elemento desde mi navegador...`<input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" id="enddate" data-toggle="datetimepicker" data-target="#enddate" name="fecha_fin" autocomplete="off" value="2019-07-17 11:07:00">`

Comment: Se me ocurre que podría ser un tema de formato, podrías indicar (editando la pregunta) como viene la fecha acá `{{$promociones->fecha_fin}}` y si tienes el enlace del componente datetimepicker que estas utilizando.

Comment: ya puse los datos que pedia amigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

asi lo resolvi amigos...en mi controlador tuve que cambiar al formato de la fecha que estaba entrando de 'Y-m-d' a 'd/m/Y y luego de eso pasar mi zona horaria de mi pais...y al final darle el formato deseado para que se guarde en la base dedatos

`$promociones->fecha_inicio = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i',$request->fecha_inicio,'America/El_Salvador')->format('Y-m-d H:i');
        $promociones->fecha_fin = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i',$request->fecha_fin,'America/El_Salvador')->format('Y-m-d H:i');`

tuve que arreglar mi script a esto

```
$('#startdate').datetimepicker({
        useCurrent: false,
        minDate: moment()
    });
    $('#enddate').datetimepicker({
        useCurrent: false,
        minDate: moment()
    });
```

y con lo del input que no mostraba el dato lo que tuve que hacer era parsearlo con el formato que utiliza el plugin del datetimepicker

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
<input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" id="startdate1" data-toggle="datetimepicker" data-target="#startdate1" name="fecha_inicio" autocomplete="off" value="{{ date('d/m/Y H:i',strtotime($promociones->fecha_inicio)) }}" />
</div>
```